# Payment Tab is missing in Facebook App settings

Tags: payment

I am facing a problem, i wanted to create a Payment mechanism for my facebook app. But according to tutorial there should be a Payment tab in the Setting menu on the App setting page. But i cannot see any payment tab there for my app. Could somebody help me in this? It will be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can't see the Canvas payments option on the left hand rail? [image]